# Split a CSV file specifying delimiter

Tags: bash, split

Is it possible to split a huge CSV file and specify the delimiter to use for the future generated files. This is my command line:

```
split -l 1000 original.csv --additional-suffix=.csv
```

Comment: How would you use the delimiter? Please post some sample data with the expected output.

Comment: Ok I just edited my post.

Comment: the `c` in `.csv` stands for comma, which means that a `csv` not containing commas can be confusing, I would save them as txt and the use `sed` to replace the `;`. `sed -i 's/,/;/g' file.txt`

Comment: It must be noted that there are many software/tools that allow using different separators with `CSV`s (e.g. excel CSV export for instance). This is convenient if the text is supposed to have commas within non-splittable contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one using awk. Notice: for file `file` it creates files named `file-1`, `file-2` etc.

It uses comma as input field separator but is there are commas in the fields (ie. `"between quotes, you know"`), they will be considered as delimiters as well. If this is the case, replace `FS=","` with `FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"` and use GNU awk.

```
$ awk -v l=2 '                    # of lines per file (l is a bit silly var name)
BEGIN {
    FS=","                        # input delimiter
    OFS=";"                       # output delimiter
    RS="\r?\n"                    # THIS FORM IS GNU AWK ONLY, use:
                                  # RS="\n" or RS="\r\n" depending on data
    if(l=="")                     # default # of lines per file
        l=1000
}
NR==1 {
    filename=FILENAME "-" (c=1)   # initial output filename
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)            # iterate all fields
        gsub(/^\"|\"$/,"",$i)     # remove quotes
    $1=$1                         # rebuild record in case no quotes were removed
    print > filename              # output to output file
    if(NR%l==0) {                 # for once mod is your friend :D
        close(filename)           # close previous open output file
        filename=FILENAME "-" ++c # form new output filename
    }
}' file
```

Output or more like results:

```
$ for f in file-? ; do echo $f: ; cat $f ; done
file-1:
51456364200024;QUALIBAT Fumisterie (Technicité courante );07/12/2015;06/12/2019
51456364200024;QUALIBAT Rénovation d'installations de chauffage (Technicité courante );07/12/2015;06/12/2019
file-2:
51456364200024;QUALITENR QualiPAC module chauffage et ECS;16/12/2018;16/12/2019
```

Comment: Yeah, just cut from: `awk ... file` and paste. You could also save to `program.awk` everything between single quotes (excluding the `'`s) and: `awk -v l=2 -f program.awk file` .

Comment: And, as there is discussion about using the comma as delimiter, you could remove the `FS` line from the code and use `-F,` (or whichever delimiter you like) from the command line (if using the `FPAT`, then you gotta replace the `,` with the whichever delimiter).

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel, there are tools to format CSV files.

Using [`csvformat`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvformat.html) from the `cvskit` package (also named `python-csvkit` or `python3-csvkit`).

I added an additional line

```
"51456364200025","A string with ""quotes,"" and, commas","16/12/2018","16/12/2019"
```

to your input to show how quotes and commas within a field are handled.

Change the delimiter to `;`:

```
$ csvformat --out-delimiter ';' input.csv
51456364200024;QUALIBAT Fumisterie (Technicité courante );07/12/2015;06/12/2019
51456364200024;QUALIBAT Rénovation d'installations de chauffage (Technicité courante );07/12/2015;06/12/2019
51456364200024;QUALITENR QualiPAC module chauffage et ECS;16/12/2018;16/12/2019
51456364200025;"A string with ""quotes,"" and, commas";16/12/2018;16/12/2019
```

Or with double quoted fields like in the input data:

```
$ csvformat --out-delimiter ';' --out-quoting 1 input.csv
"51456364200024";"QUALIBAT Fumisterie (Technicité courante )";"07/12/2015";"06/12/2019"
"51456364200024";"QUALIBAT Rénovation d'installations de chauffage (Technicité courante )";"07/12/2015";"06/12/2019"
"51456364200024";"QUALITENR QualiPAC module chauffage et ECS";"16/12/2018";"16/12/2019"
"51456364200025";"A string with ""quotes,"" and, commas";"16/12/2018";"16/12/2019"
```

Since `split` named your output files `xaa.csv`, `xab.csv` etc., you could modify your output files with a loop like

```
for i in x*.csv; do
  csvformat --out-delimiter ';' "$i" > temp && mv temp "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'sed' to replace the quotes and commas.

```
<your command> | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/,/;/g'
```

or you can use

```
cat <csv_file_name> | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/,/;/g'
```

If you want to save your changes you can use 'sed -i '.